# How to Prevent Same Record / Twice MySQL - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I use a 3rd party payment solution on my app.

After a member make a payment (3-4 seconds), 3rd party **payment site will redirect the member** our web site.

**At the same time, payment site sends a request** to our web site about every payment.

If payment info request coincides with redirect user request, the system saves two times. *To prevent twice recording, I use an unique ID on DB for every payment.*

```
$unique_id = $_GET['unique_id'];
## ask the DB this this unique ID exist?
if($exist){
  //update some tables
  //delete the unique id 
}
else{
   //it was done before
}
```

Let's say the unique ID **asd89279182jkfhff1249879**
if two same request come to our web site at the same second and unique id is exist, the script will do job twice.

```
mywebsite.com/a.php?unique_id=asd89279182jkfhff1249879
```

How can I prevent twice record for this situation?

Comment: Note it's spelled "unique", not "uniqe".

Answer (score 1):

Normally you don't test and then insert, you just insert and check for errors because you've set up a [`UNIQUE` constraint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html) on that column.

If you try and insert into a table where that unique value is already taken you'll get an error of the "duplicate key" variety. It's actually impossible to add two with the same ID.

You can also do things like add an `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause to define additional behaviour, like to update the record with new data.

Comment: just, I want to be sure, If I set the created_at (timestamp) is unique, saving same date (2020-02-23 11:24) will be impossible, am I right? Even if two requests were sent exactly at the same time?

Comment: A) Don't use `TIMESTAMP` columns, they're trash. Not only do they update when you don't expect them to, but they literally stop working in 2038, which is not that far away now. Use a regular `DATETIME` instead. B) Using a time as a unique key is asking for trouble as that limits you to no more than one entry per second with second-granularity times, or random and unwanted collisions later if you use milliseconds.

Comment: Normally when interfacing with payment systems they'll give you a payment identifier of some kind which is unique. You'd have a table with a `UNIQUE` constraint to record these to avoid duplication. Most providers send some kind of webhook notification that can come before or after the visitor returns, but you can usually verify a payment ID with an API call if the visitor shows up early.

Comment: you are right. Actually I have unique ID for every payment request, and, when I get answer of payment request; **I check DB with that unique ID, if exist,** I update user/payment tables, then, **delete that ID.**

**BUT**

Sometimes, two diffrent $_GET answers of one payment request can come for same result. 

If the two _GET request are clashed at the same second, somehow, "updating user/payment tables" done twice? (this problem frequency is arround 3%)

Comment: When doing *anything* involving money try and use a ledger, not a balance table, that is record individual transactions and depend on the `SUM()` of those values to determine balances. If you have a `UNIQUE` constraint you won't have clashes, you'll have one succeed and one fail. Generally you preserve data in the ledger, you never delete it, so you have an accurate record of all account activity, something very useful when tracking down problems.

Comment: For A.)
Okay I will update TIMESTAMP to DATETIME. Is there any using diffrences on  PHP side? when inserting, updating and/or showing. Do I need to change anything after this changing on PHP app date fields/functions.

B.) You are again right. Actually, I have two diffrent dates. 1.) created_at for writing DB, the other one is payment result date (payment_date). and exclude of these, I have a unique ID for payment request.

Is this possible on MySQL side:
payment ID and payment_date must be together unique?

Comment: As far as PHP goes, just try and insert it, and if it bounces back with a "duplicate key" error then you've already inserted that unique ID previously. It really depends on your payment provider. I'm more familiar with Stripe, but PayPal doesn't work all that differently.

Answer (score 0):

You could `UPSERT` values to your table.
We can imitate MySQL UPSERT in one of these three ways:

1. UPSERT using INSERT IGNORE
2. UPSERT using REPLACE
3. UPSERT using INSERT with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

or set `PRIMARY KEY` and `UNIQUE Index` for your id can prevent duplicating in your data